# What do these numbers mean in syslog?

Tags: mysql, ram, log

I'm trying to determine why MySQL server process is being killed due to out of memory, so am looking at the sylog.
Immediately before the 'out of memory' I see lots of lines with differing numbers but I can't find out what they mean.
Please can someone shed some light on what I'm looking at and if it gives any clues to my problem.

```
Jun 29 15:21:33 serverpilottest kernel: [1320544.512442] [ 3158]  1000  3158        97824     2881     107     1172             0 php-fpm
Jun 29 15:21:33 serverpilottest kernel: [1320544.512443] [ 3160]  1000  3160     96548     1610     105     1194             0 php-fpm
Jun 29 15:21:33 serverpilottest kernel: [1320544.512445] [ 3161]  1000  3161    95737      806     104     1224             0 php-fpm
Jun 29 15:21:33 serverpilottest kernel: [1320544.512448] Out of memory: Kill process 1598 (mysqld) score 68 or sacrifice child
```

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For what the output means see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/128667/119298). Note that mysql is probably not the cause of the problem. Linux by default overcommits memory and then when processes actually start to use it, it has to kill some other process to get some memory.

Often it chooses whatever is big and not much used. You can protect a process from being killed by doing

```
echo -1000 > /proc/999/oom_score_adj
```

where 999 is the process id. See `man proc`. The value is -1000 to +1000 to bias the oom killer (less likely to more likely), with -1000 = dont ever kill.

You should monitor process memory sizes, eg with `top` (type `M` to sort by memory).

The output is from the oom manager. `php-fpm` is probably part of apache. You can often configure apache to kill much reused threads that have grown too much; its a choice between faster cgi and less memory being wasted.

You can temporarily disable overcommitting memory with

```
sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=2
```

then you are more likely to have the memory-hogging process crash, instead of some random process being killed. It's not usually recommended as a permanent setting.

Comment: Please add some explanation about what `-17` do to the `oom_adj` file..also normally its not a good idea to keeping a process hogging up the memory while others are craving for it..

Comment: I spotted this in the logs: oom_adj is deprecated - use oom_score_adj

Comment: @GeoffM you are right. I've edited the answer. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

These look like process id, user id, and again process id, respectively. Can't see what is in the last column, probably some indication of memory usage.